# AttributeError: module 'myapp' has no attribute 'startswith' in Django

Tags: django

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x046E1780>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BS146\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BS146\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\BS146\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\BS146\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\BS146\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BS146\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\BS146\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\BS146\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\BS146\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 117, in import_module
    if name.startswith('.'):
AttributeError: module 'myapp' has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `INSTALLED_APPS` has an entry that is not a string.

It should be

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [..., 'myapp']
```

, not

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [..., myapp]
```